# Limit access to skills for user groups

Tags: botframework

I'm working on the design with core bot and few skills connected to it. I'm looking for the solution design to limit the access for a given skills inside the organization.
Example:
Core bot - access for all employees
Finance skill - access for finance team
HR skill - access for all employees

I'm already familiar with RBAC concept e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0&preserve-view=true#adding-role-checks

I'm looking for the suggestions how to implement it with botframework, and how to store the role assignments.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this would be through the use of SSO and bot authentication ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)). Essentially, you can have your users with their preset roles and permissions log into the root bot, and SSO allows that auth to pass to skills.

You cannot completely block the ability to communicate with a skill, but implementing auth will allow you to prevent unauthorized users (say an engineer accessing a payroll skill) from using any of the skill's commands.

Comment: Think you @AP01. Do you have any suggestions how or where to store the access table/database?

Comment: You don't store an explicit table per say, you make use of an authentication provider (which can be Azure Active Directory) and configure it within the bot.

See the [Bot Framework Auth Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for more detailed explanations of how auth works. There are also samples that show how to do it.